# Accessing TextBox.Text on dynamically added UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, user-controls

On load of a new Window I add a dynamic number of UserControls (SetInformation) to my window as below

```
public Window_NewWorkoutLine(int NoOfSets, int workoutLineId)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    currentWorkoutLineId = workoutLineId;

    for (int x = 1; x <= NoOfSets; x++)
    {
        SetInformation setInformation = new SetInformation(x);
        StackPanel_Main.Children.Add(setInformation);
    }
}
```

Each of the UserControls contains 2 textboxes, what I need to do is grab the Text property from each textbox on each UserControl and use them in an insert query to a database. The data from each UserControl will be added to a seperate row in the database.

Any ideas guys?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you would do mvvm  then you would not have this problem. then you would create new Viemodels to your Mainviewmodel and show them in your view with some binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try adding a public property to your control to get and set text to the text boxes:

```
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return txtTextBox.Text.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            txtTextBox.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could enumerate all UIElement or "StackPanel_Main", and then cast them.
For example (with use of System.Linq) :

```
        foreach (SetInformation setInformation in StackPanel_Main.Children.OfType<SetInformation>())
        {
            string txt1 = setInformation.Text1;
            string txt2 = setInformation.Text2;
        }
```

But I think this would be better to associate a "Value Object" to each instance of your UserControl to separate User Interface (UI) from Data. You could do that with Binding for example.
First declare your class which will contain your data with implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged for UI integration :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This objet contains all useful data
    /// </summary>
    public class InformationValueObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _text1;
        private string _text2;

        public string Text1
        {
            get { return _text1; }
            set { _text1 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Text1"); }
        }

        public string Text2
        {
            get { return _text2; }
            set { _text2 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Text2"); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Then add Binding to your UserControl, as you like, for example you could just set the DataContext of your UserControl like bellow, and then Bind each property to each TextBox from DataContext :

```
public partial class Window_NewWorkoutLine : Window
{

    private List<InformationValueObject> _valueObjects = new List<InformationValueObject>();

    public Window_NewWorkoutLine(int NoOfSets, int workoutLineId)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        currentWorkoutLineId = workoutLineId;

        for (int x = 1; x <= NoOfSets; x++)
        {
            SetInformation setInformation = new SetInformation(x);
            InformationValueObject vo = new InformationValueObject();
            setInformation.DataContext = _vo;
            _valueObjects.Add(vo);
            StackPanel_Main.Children.Add(setInformation);
        }
    }
}
```

It is then easy to retrieve values by reading private collection "_valueObjects". No more need to enumerate User Interface composition.

It is really important to separate data and display.
My example could also be improved a lot.
For example, a ListView is composed (by default) by a StackPanel inside a ScrollViewer, and you can set the "ItemsSource" property with _valueObjects collection, and customize Item template to use your custom UserControl.
Then you can improve again by using a [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) model with the Binding of your collection onto your ListBox.  You could also use an `ObservableCollection<InformationValueObject>` instead of a `List<InformationValueObject>` if you want to be able to add or remove items dynamically...
I know this is not possible to masterize everything, but I think it could be great to tend to these solutions by separating data and visualization.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can add accessors to the user controls:

```
public class SetInformation{
    private TextBox box1;
    private TextBox box2;

    public string Box1Text{
        get{
            return box1.Text;
        }
    }

    public string Box2Text{
        get{
            return box2.Text;
        }
    }
...
...
}
```